# Raspberry Pi 4 working as Apple TV

Tags: pi-4, openelec, osmc, xbian

Is there any way to stream video & audio from my iOS/macOS device to my Smart TV (Samsung) using a RaspberryPi 4?

I have been reading about OSMC, OpenElec, and XBian. It seems that OSMC is the most interesting option, but I have not been able to find if it already compatible with RaspberryPi 4 nor how to install in the raspberry

To sum up: Can I convert my RaspberryPi 4 into an AppleTV like device?

Comment: Not possible or it would have been done by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this: https://github.com/FD-/RPiPlay

I tried doing screen mirroring from mac and iPhone, and played some videos from image gallery.

Don't know how suitable for streaming video apps (nflx, hbo did not work for me).

Answer (score 3):

Packages like Volumio with give you the ability to stream music over Airplay (inc Airplay 2) but the TV side is not supported by anything outside of the Apple boxes.

LibreELEC (and Kodi) is now supported on a Pi 4 [V9.2 here](https://libreelec.tv/raspberry-pi-4/)

OSMC only goes to Pi 3B+ [Downloads here](https://osmc.tv/download/) - I think they are pushing you to the Vero 4K+ boxes rather than a Pi solution.

OpenELEC is also not available for the Pi 4 [downloads here](https://openelec.tv/downloads)